# Processing JSON using java Mapreduce

Tags: json, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to hadoop mapreduce

I have input text file where data has been stored as follow. Here are only a few tuples (data.txt)

```
{"author":"Sharīf Qāsim","book":"al- Rabīʻ al-manshūd"}
{"author":"Nāṣir Nimrī","book":"Adīb ʻAbbāsī"}
{"author":"Muẓaffar ʻAbd al-Majīd Kammūnah","book":"Asmāʼ Allāh al-ḥusná al-wāridah fī muḥkam kitābih"}
{"author":"Ḥasan Muṣṭafá Aḥmad","book":"al- Jabhah al-sharqīyah wa-maʻārikuhā fī ḥarb Ramaḍān"}
{"author":"Rafīqah Salīm Ḥammūd","book":"Taʻlīm fī al-Baḥrayn"}
```

This is my java file that I am supposed to write my code in (CombineBooks.java)

```
package org.hwone;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

//TODO import necessary components

/*
*  Modify this file to combine books from the same other into
*  single JSON object. 
*  i.e. {"author": "Tobias Wells", "books": [{"book":"A die in the country"},{"book": "Dinky died"}]}
*  Beaware that, this may work on anynumber of nodes! 
*
*/

public class CombineBooks {

  //TODO define variables and implement necessary components

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args)
                .getRemainingArgs();
    if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
      System.err.println("Usage: CombineBooks <in> <out>");
      System.exit(2);
    }

    //TODO implement CombineBooks

    Job job = new Job(conf, "CombineBooks");

    //TODO implement CombineBooks

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

My task is to create a Hadoop program in “CombineBooks.java”
returned in the “question-2” directory. The program should do
the following: Given the input author-book tuples, map-reduce
program should procude a JSON object which contains all the
books from same author in a JSON array, i.e.

```
{"author": "Tobias Wells", "books":[{"book":"A die in the country"},{"book": "Dinky died"}]}
```

**Any idea how it can be done ?**

Comment: What about using Apache Drill and SQL ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, the JSON objects you are trying to work with are not available for you. To solve this:

1. Go here and download as zip: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java
2. Extract to your sources folder in subdirectory org/json/*

Next, the first line of your code makes a package "org.json", which is incorrect, you shold create a separate package, for instance "my.books".

Third, using combiner here is useless.

Here's the code I ended up with, it works and solves your problem:

```
package my.books;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
import org.json.*;

import javax.security.auth.callback.TextInputCallback;

public class CombineBooks {

    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>{

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

            String author;
            String book;
            String line = value.toString();
            String[] tuple = line.split("\\n");
            try{
                for(int i=0;i<tuple.length; i++){
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(tuple[i]);
                    author = obj.getString("author");
                    book = obj.getString("book");
                    context.write(new Text(author), new Text(book));
                }
            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text,Text,NullWritable,Text>{

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

            try{
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
                for(Text val : values){
                    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject().put("book", val.toString());
                    ja.put(jo);
                }
                obj.put("books", ja);
                obj.put("author", key.toString());
                context.write(NullWritable.get(), new Text(obj.toString()));
            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: CombineBooks <in> <out>");
            System.exit(2);
        }

        Job job = new Job(conf, "CombineBooks");
        job.setJarByClass(CombineBooks.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Here's the folder structure of my project:

```
src
src/my
src/my/books
src/my/books/CombineBooks.java
src/org
src/org/json
src/org/json/zip
src/org/json/zip/BitReader.java
...
src/org/json/zip/None.java
src/org/json/JSONStringer.java
src/org/json/JSONML.java
...
src/org/json/JSONException.java
```

Here's the input

```
[localhost:CombineBooks]$ hdfs dfs -cat /example.txt
{"author":"author1", "book":"book1"}
{"author":"author1", "book":"book2"}
{"author":"author1", "book":"book3"}
{"author":"author2", "book":"book4"}
{"author":"author2", "book":"book5"}
{"author":"author3", "book":"book6"}
```

The command to run:

```
hadoop jar ./bookparse.jar my.books.CombineBooks /example.txt /test_output
```

Here's the output:

```
[pivhdsne:CombineBooks]$ hdfs dfs -cat /test_output/part-r-00000
{"books":[{"book":"book3"},{"book":"book2"},{"book":"book1"}],"author":"author1"}
{"books":[{"book":"book5"},{"book":"book4"}],"author":"author2"}
{"books":[{"book":"book6"}],"author":"author3"}
```

You can use on of the three options to put the `org.json.*` classes into your cluster:

1. Pack the `org.json.*` classes into your jar file (can easily be done using GUI IDE). This is the option I used in my answer
2. Put the jar file containing `org.json.*` classes on each of the cluster nodes into one of the CLASSPATH directories (see yarn.application.classpath)
3. Put the jar file containing `org.json.*` into HDFS (`hdfs dfs -put <org.json jar> <hdfs path>`) and use `job.addFileToClassPath` call for this jar file to be available for all of the tasks executing your job on the cluster. In my answer you should add `job.addFileToClassPath(new Path("<jar_file_on_hdfs_location>"));` to the `main`

Comment: +1 This solution is not complete without `job.addFileToClassPath` statement. Please do add.

Comment: It depends. You can build `org.json` contents as a separate jar file and manually place it on each of the cluster nodes in a `CLASSPATH` directory (it is preferred solution as JSON parsing is a common task). Or you can put both `org.json` and `my.books` to a single jar, then you won't have to use `job.addFileToClassPath`. Or you can build it as a separate jar file and use `job.addFileToClassPath` to ship it to the cluster nodes on the execution time. You have to choose an option based on the context of the task, for production I'd prefer 1, for development and debuging - 2 or 3

Comment: Adding the same lines to the answer will benefit anyone who looks for this post. Without this knowledge, they will get into another exception, if haven't encountered previously. That's my intention.

Comment: added to the solution

Comment: @0x0FFF.. its really awesome  , Can U please let me know How to generate JAR file in Ubuntu Terminal , Please help me,,, this is the quesiton i posted    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35030016/unable-to-generate-jar-file-for-hadoop

Answer (score 0):

Refer for splittable multi-line JSON: 
https://github.com/alexholmes/json-mapreduce