# Does Google BigQuery supports Parquet file format?

Tags: google-bigquery, parquet

I was wondering if Google BigQuery currently supports [Parquet file format](https://parquet.apache.org/documentation/latest/) or if there are plans to support it?

I know that it currently supports CSV and JSON formats.

Comment: Thanks for the request. I have opened a feature request for adding Parquet. Please add your use case there. It will help us evaluate the outside interest. Here it is: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=355&thanks=355&ts=1446053772

Answer (score 9, accepted):

** **As of 1st March 2018, Support for [loading Parquet 1.0 files](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-parquet) is available.**

In the BigQuery CLI, there is `--source_format PARQUET` option which is described in output of `bq --help`.

I never got to use it, because when I was experimenting with this feature, it was still invite-only, and I did not request the invite.

My usecase was that the Parquet file is half the size of the Avro file. I wanted to try something new and upload data efficiently (in this order).

```
% bq load --source_format PARQUET test.test3 data.avro.parquet schema.json 
Upload complete.
Waiting on bqjob_r5b8a2b16d964eef7_0000015b0690a06a_1 ... (0s) Current 
status: DONE   
[...]
```

Comment: The error you got said "not enabled". In this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905411 I see mentions of projects being enabled to use this. Perhaps this is just a matter of the feature being 'beta' and needs to be enabled for you to experiment with.

Comment: To complement this answer: Parquet can be loaded correctly into BigQuery if we use the "WriterVersion PARQUET_1_0" version.
If instead the Parquet files uses PARQUET_2_0, then Parquet cannot be loaded into BigQuery: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116699318

Answer (score 1):

At this time BigQuery does not support Parquet file format. However, we are interested to hear more about your use case - are you interested in import, export or both ? How do you intend to use it ? Understanding the scenarios better will help BigQuery team to plan accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I do not have any specific use case at the moment. We currently import CSV files into BigQuery and I was wondering if it would still work if we changed the format to Parquet. 

Storing the files in Parquet or ORC would allow us the flexibility to also be able to analyse the files in Hadoop in a faster way than with CSV files.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share a file format between BigQuery and Hadoop, you can use newline separated JSON records.

BigQuery supports these for import and export.

Hadoop supports this as well. Searching the internets finds many hits showing recipes for making it work. Here's one: [Processing JSON using java Mapreduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26659753/processing-json-using-java-mapreduce)

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with hundreds of millions of rows and need to move data to an on-premise Hadoop cluster, this is, exporting from bigQuery, json is just not feasible option, avro not much better, the only efficient option today for such movement of data is gz which is unfortunately not possible to be read natively in Hadoop, Larquet is the only efficient way for this use case, we do not have any other efficient option

Answer (score 0):

Eample (**part-*** is the secret sauce here):

```
bq load --source_format=PARQUET --replace=true abc.def gs://abc/def/part-*
```