# Unable to generate jar file for Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, mapreduce

I have 16 Java files and I am trying to generate JAR files for the Hadoop ecosystem using the below command:

```
javac -classpath /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-core-1.0.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar  JsonV.java
```

**JsonV.java** is the class which has main function and this Java file calls other Java files. I am getting this below error, can anybody help me resolve this please?

```
JsonV.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(tuple[i]);
                     ^ 
  symbol:   class JSONObject
  location: class Map
JsonV.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(tuple[i]);
                                         ^
  symbol:   class JSONObject
  location: class Map
JsonV.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
            }catch(JSONException e){
                   ^
  symbol:   class JSONException
  location: class Map
JsonV.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
            }catch(JSONException e){
                   ^
  symbol:   class JSONException
  location: class Reduce
```

Comment: and i tried this in eclipse and it working fine over there ,

Comment: This sounds like a dependancy problem to me

Comment: may be,, I have other java files and I have stored them in a single package

Comment: and you said you're able to create a JAR in eclipse?

Comment: s sir , But i am not getting in ubuntu terminal,, and the Jar file generated from eclipse is not working in hadoop also

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 7 & javax.json lib, you don`t need to include any external files. But if you use Java 6 & org.json lib, you have to add JAR explicitly. But it seems it works in eclipse. So I guess you are using jdk6 with hadoop. If you change it to jdk 7 for hadoop, the problem will be solved.

It works in eclipse because you configured your build path with jdk 7.

If you use maven, you have to mention the json lib dependencies in pom.xml file.

If you don't use maven, just copy paste your json lib jars in hadoop lib dir and restart hadoop. It will work.

Comment: I dont have any other external jar files to parse Json data ,, I have only the JAVA files,,,and I stored all the jar files in single package

Comment: If you use  Java 7 & javax.json lib, you don`t need to include any external files. But if you use Java 6 & org.json lib, you have to add JAR explicitly. But it seems it works in eclipse. So I guess you are using jdk6 with hadoop. If you change it to jdk 7 for hadoop, the problem will be solved

Comment: sir i am using org.json ligrary with JDK7 , so it is working properly in eclipse,,,How to parse json data using javax.json lib

Comment: Hadoop 1 is compatible with JDK 6 for mapreduce jobs. So please run this with jdk 6 and org.json lib files